# ListSelectionListener not working with pop up JFrame window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, listselectionlistener

I am having issues getting a JList to work correctly with a ListSelectionListener, i;ve tried both an anonymous inner class and adding to my Handler class and implementing it and neither are working...

What's happening is I have a JFrame window with a JComboBox and when you click on "Color List" a new JFrame window pops up which has a JList on it and the options are supposed to change the background color...everything is good except the background color is not changing when I click the options.  I'll just post the appropriate code...

```
private static String[] colorNames = {"Black", "Blue", "Red", "White"};
private static Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.WHITE};

public void colorListOption() {
    TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();

    newFrame2 = new JFrame();

    panel3 = new JPanel();
    newFrame2.setTitle("Welcome to The Color List!");
    newFrame2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    newFrame2.setSize(500, 300);
    newFrame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(newFrame2.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    

    colorList = new JList(colorNames);
    colorList.setVisibleRowCount(4);
    colorList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    colorList.setOpaque(false);
    panel3.add(new JScrollPane(colorList));
    newFrame2.add(panel3);  

    colorList.addListSelectionListener(
        new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent ls) {
                panel3.setBackground(colors[colorList.getSelectedIndex()]);
            }
        }
    );

    newFrame2.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with the listener not firing and not a problem with the background color not changing? I.e. try putting a print statement in the listener and see if prints.

Comment: Ok will do, I'll let you know.

Comment: Ok yeah you're right it's not a problem with the Listener it's a problem with the background color not changing....any tips?

Comment: I think that the background color won't update until the component is repainted. You can do a getContentPane().repaint() just after you set the background.

Comment: No that didn't work either...